# youtube.videos().insert AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'videos'

Tags: python, video, youtube

I am coding this very simple example to try to decrypt one of the examples given by the youtube API v3 examples. For what I read [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#examples), the method videos.insert should be available in order to upload a given video, but python returns :

```
    youtube.videos().insert
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'videos'
```

In order to discover what is going on, I have re-installed my virtualenv and I have installed google-api-client lib via easyinstall --upgrade. It has installed me the following libs :

```
google-api-python-client==1.4.2
httplib2==0.9.2
oauth2client==1.5.2
pyasn1==0.1.9
pyasn1-modules==0.0.8
rsa==3.3
simplejson==3.8.1
six==1.10.0
uritemplate==0.6
wheel==0.26.0
```

This method is not available, but the imports are fine ( no error on imports )

The pseudo-code :

```
import httplib2
import os
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenCredentials
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenRefreshError
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
import urllib


def authenticate():
    #scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload"
    service = build('youtube', 'v3', http=http)
    acc_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    flow = AccessTokenCredentials(
        acc_token, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36')
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = flow.authorize(http)


def initialize_upload(youtube):
    tags = None
    youtube.videos().insert
    media_body = MediaFileUpload('1977.mp4', mimetype='video/mp4',
                                 chunksize=1024 * 1024, resumable=True)


def execute():
    youtube = authenticate()
    initialize_upload(youtube)

execute()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `authenticate` function contains no `return` statements, hence its return value is `None`. The error is an obvious consequence of this.

You probably wanted to `return service`. Though I believe your code contains other errors, since you are trying to pass an `http` argument to `build` which is defined afterwards.

Comment: you were right, I had to return(service) I don't get any error output now, but on reference to what you have said about trying to pass an http argument to build, the code example from youtube is `return build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))` , wich is passing the token / user agent flow. I got no errors now, how can I get an output of what's going on ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is link that got me started with uploading. I'm now working on refreshing my auth token.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video